# Would question about database recommendation be on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, asking-questions

I am developing desktop application that will need a database. App will only run on Windows.

My problem comes from not being able to afford SQL Server Enterprise Edition, and Express Edition has maximum database size limit.

I wanted to ask on the main site for help about working around the maximum size limit of the SQL Server Express Edition, so I could use it, or if the previous is impossible, for recommendation of an alternative solution.

Would this type of question be on topic?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[database-recommendation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-recommendation) questions are not off-topic, but experience has shown that they need to be better than average to avoid being ignored or closed, especially in recent times. Click on that tag to see existing questions.

Be specific about the circumstances, requirements, and constraints you face up front. For example, you should say whether the application is for development/testing or production use. Questions that are open-ended, require extended discussion, or attract answers based mostly on opinion are very likely to be closed.

Read through the advice in the Help Centre before composing your final question:

- [How do I ask a good question?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)
- [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)
- [What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)

Somewhat related meta questions you might like to review:

- [Are questions on preferring a db type, brand for some app tasks on topic?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2408/1192)
- [Where can I ask about how to handle certain load?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2363/1192)

Answer (score 8):

Questions about how to circumvent licensing restrictions are off-topic, for obvious legal reasons.

However, you're welcome to ask for database recommendations, just make sure your question is clearly defined.

Comment: After reading through the accepted answer, I believe I can indeed manage to write a good question. Thank you for your advice. I haven't accepted your answer officially because the accepted one offered more detailed explanation. Regards. +1