# What's wrong with this database recommendation question?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, asking-questions

A while ago I asked [this database recommendation question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/171440/what-databases-can-i-use-to-represent-ordered-sets) and it was immediately downvoted/flagged. I've edited it several times to try to clarify what I'm asking, but no matter how I try to explain my requirements it doesn't seem to gain any traction. It's now closed. How can I further edit this question to be a good fit for this site?

Answer (score 12):

I edited and upvoted your question because I found it on-topic and interesting. That said, other members of the community had already voted to close it, and left it closed after an automatic [reopen review](https://dba.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/91355) triggered by one of your edits.

Also, experience has shown that database recommendation questions [have to be pretty exceptional](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2507/1192) to remain open here. On balance, I did not feel the question warranted reopening (by me alone) as it currently stands.

I think a concrete real-world example would help your question immensely, though I expect you are still most likely to get SQL answers here.

As an *alternative*, you might look at [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) - be sure to read their FAQ and [question quality guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) if you do decide to go that route.

The question has now been reopened by community vote.

Comment: I've added one more concrete example, but without knowing the answer to my own question I don't think I can do much better

Comment: @EricB By "concrete example", I mean details of an actual real-world requirement, with expected data volumes etc.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't vote to close, mainly because I didn't see this question in the review queue. I'm not sure what I would have done if I did.

After the edits it's probably not unclear, even if it's a domain I'm not familiar with. I probably would have skipped it but there is a thin line between [database-recommendation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-recommendation) and shopping list question (which is off-topic).

I've voted to reopen now mainly because it's not unclear to me and you seem to care enough to raise it on meta, however I would understand if people voted to close it as shopping list.

I think maybe a question about "what *types* of databases" instead of "what databases" would evade the chances of it being a shopping list question, but that's just semantics I suppose and I'm not trying to be pedantic. As I said, not my domain.

Comment: you've convinced me.  I've voted to reopen now as well.

Answer (score 3):

I was the first person to vote to close your question.  I did that because I felt the question was unclear because it did not address what you meant by modifying the order of a linked-list without needing to modify the links.  Of note; I left several comments on your question that have since been cleaned up.

My answer was an attempt to get you to update the question with details showing why my answer does not address your requirement.

Since your updated question shows why you consider standard SQL not viable, I have deleted my answer (FYI, it remains visible to high-rep users).

As Paul suggested in his answer, I also think you need to show a concrete example of how you suggest a linked-list can be reordered without any significant work.  Once you add those details, I expect the question might be re-opened.